# Not able to send mails to personal email using php

Tags: php, phpmailer

Need the solution for :

---

I have written a code in PHP where in Im able to send emails to gmail id with help of phpmailer , but with same code im not able to mail to personal domain email which is a.v@msdesigns.co.in.

When I obsevered the issue the emailid which taken is chopped to a.v@msdesigns only instead of a.v@msdesigns.co.in.

### *Code that I have Tried*

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'./PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');

$To = htmlentities($_POST['sendersName']);
echo $To;

$From = htmlentities($_POST['sendersEmail']);
echo $From;

$Subject = htmlentities($_POST['sendersMessage']);
echo $Subject;


$mail  = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Body ="Name :-" .$To. "\n <br>"."From :-" .$From. "\n <br>"."Subject :-"  .$Subject. "\n <br>";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;                 #enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";               #sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host  = "smtp.gmail.com";         #sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                 #set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "a@gmail.com";                  #your gmail username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";                  #Your gmail password
$mail->From       = $From;             #your gmail id
$mail->FromName   = $To;                 #your name 
$mail->Subject    = "Message From".$To;


$mail->WordWrap   = 150;
$mail->AddAddress("a@gmail.com","abc");
$mail->AddAddress("a@gmail.com","abc");

$mail->AddAddress("a.v@msdesigns.co.in","Msd");
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}

?>
```

1. Please let me know why only a.v@msdesigns is considered and not
   a.v@msdesigns.co.in
2. Please let me know how to send mails to my personal domain that is msdesigns.co.in

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvoting the questions. Im quite new to php

Comment: If you can successfully send emails to an `@gmail` domain but not your personal domain, then the problem is with your personal domain configuration, not the code.

Comment: Base your code on [the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), not random obsolete code you found elsewhere, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Comment: But as I have mentioned the email is a.v@msdesigns.co.in but the email is getting sent to a.v@msdesigns

If the email is considered or taken as a.v@msdesigns.co.in will solve this.
Im not getting why its considering only a.v@msdesigns instead of a.v@msdesigns.co.in